# Какие бесплатные версии MVS я могу установить?

Tags: visual-studio, лицензирование

Какие из бесплатных последний версий microsoft visual studio я могу установить в не коммерческих целях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из последних -- [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx). Сравнение редакций по фичам [тут](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Вроде как есть Visual Studio 2015 Community .

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Answer (score 2):

Express и Community. Первая предоставляется уже очень давно, вторая появилась с приходом Visual Studio 2015 и в отличие от Express-редакции поддерживает установку плагинов